# Who or what is a "J.G. Scrunt"?

Tags: terminology, lady-in-the-water

In the M. Night Shyamalan film ***Lady in the Water***, the character of Story — a water nymph from the "Blue World" — is tormented by a grass-covered wolf-like creature called a "Scrunt".

[image: The green Scrunt]

Amongst the many times that the Scrunt is mentioned in the film, there are **exactly two instances** where it is referred to as what sounds like **"the J.G. Scrunt"**.

> *What is the **J.G. Scrunt's** reaction? Is he frightened?*

A few moments later:

> *The Guardian can control his mind. The **J.G. Scrunt** will not
>   be able to attack.*

I don't have access to an official screenplay, but [this version](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=lady-in-the-water) of the script agrees with my hearing of "J.G. Scrunt".  The "J.G." prefix is inconsistent within the film (it is only used those two times) and it is not explained in any dialogue.

**Is "J.G. Scrunt" actually being said?  If so, is "J.G." an out-of-universe reference to something or someone?**

I have seen chatter that it might be a tongue-in-cheek reference to a writer / director / producer / critic, but no verification of this.

Comment: Junior Grade, presumably. The scrunt is subordinate to a higher power...

Comment: @Richard : Good thought, but not especially consistent with Story's origin and way of speaking.  "Junior grade" doesn't seem like a phrase that would be used in the Blue World (let alone shortening it to an acronym).  But I could be wrong...

Comment: Looking at subtitle files it seems others agree it's "JG scrunt" FWIW.

Comment: I saw someone [claiming](http://www.mnightfans.com/forums/index.php?topic=798.15) that it meant something in Hindi.

Comment: Jade Green ? (long shot)

Answer (score -3):

I was puzzled by the name J.G. in reference to the Scrunt as well. Then I decided maybe she was saying RG Scrunt as in a Rogue Scrunt like Lin Su's mother spoke of. She recognizes the Scrunt as a rule breaker that is very dangerous because he is not afraid of his inevitable punishment. Of course it seems to me that there is always some small tiny detail in all Shylaman's films that bewilders me.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that she was actually saying RG instead of JG? R and J don't sound too much alike.